# Postgres - adding an aggregate function from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay so I start with this query that works well:

```
SELECT org.organization_id, org.comp_code, org.name, cust.name as customer,
o.order_number as number, o.order_id as id, cast(o.total_charge as real) as receivable 
    FROM 
    organization as org, orders as o, organization as cust, 
    reconcile_order as ro
    WHERE org.organization_id = o.shipper_org_id
    and o.broker_org_id = cust.organization_id
    and o.order_id = ro.order_id
    and o.status = 'D'
    and org.comp_code = 'ABC'
    and (ro.receive_payment_in_full = 0 or ro.receive_payment_in_full is NULL)
```

But now I want add a sum from another table for each order_id. This other table is called reconcile_receivables and it has a column called amount. But the trick is that multiple amounts can relate to a unique order_id. So, I need to sum these amounts for every unique order. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT org.organization_id, org.comp_code, org.name, cust.name as customer,
o.order_number as number, o.order_id as id, cast(o.total_charge as real) as receivable, 
sum(rr.amount) as partial_pay 
    FROM
    organization as org, orders as o, organization as cust,
    reconcile_order as ro, reconcile_receivables as rr
    WHERE org.organization_id = o.shipper_org_id
    and o.broker_org_id = cust.organization_id
    and o.order_id = ro.order_id
    and o.order_id = rr.order_id
    and o.status = 'D'
    and org.comp_code = 'ABC'
    and (ro.receive_payment_in_full = 0 or ro.receive_payment_in_full is NULL)
```

My problem is I get this error:

```
column "org.organization_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause
or be used in an aggregate function
```

Adding a group by clause doesn't help. So how can I solve this to show a column that represents the sum of every rr.amount related to each o.order_id? For example, there are two rr.amount values whose sum is 1000 and they relate to order_id = 3. So for that row, it should show sum amount column with the value of 1000

Comment: Add the non aggregate columns in `Group by`

Answer (score 1):

You should do what PostgreSQL recommends and add a `GROUP BY` clause.

You will have to add *all* columns from the output list that are *not* in an aggregate function like `sum()` or `count()`.

As an aside, is it possible that there are `orders` for which there is no `reconcile_receivables`? In that case you should use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Your aside is correct, so I did `left outer join rr on o.order_id = rr.order_id` and then added all the other conditions below that. However, now I get a `relation rr does not exist` error which is strange

Comment: `rr` doesn't exist. `left outer join reconcile_receivables rr on ...`

Comment: I tried that too but now I get `table name "rr" specified more than once` so then when I remove my earlier specification of rr I get `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "o"` I am stuck in a loop of errors.

Comment: It seems that you are not familiar with ANSI join syntax. Instead of `FROM organization as org, orders as o, organization as cust, reconcile_order as ro, reconcile_receivables as rr WHERE o.order_id = rr.order_id` use `FROM organization as org, organization as cust, reconcile_order as ro, orders as o LEFT OUTER JOIN reconcile_receivables as rr ON o.order_id = rr.order_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function, replace problem column with this:

```
sum(rr.amount) over(partition by order.id) as partial_pay
```

I think it can help

UPD I see entire query text and I found, that you can use such query:

```
SELECT org.organization_id,..., sum(rr.amount) as partial_pay FROM organization as org, orders as o, organization as cust, reconcile_order as ro, (select sum(amount) as amount, order_id FROM reconcile_receivables GROUP BY order_id) as rr WHERE org.organization_id = o.shipper_org_id and o.broker_org_id = cust.organization_id and o.order_id = ro.order_id and o.order_id = rr.order_id and o.status = 'D' and org.comp_code = 'ABC' and (ro.receive_payment_in_full = 0 or ro.receive_payment_in_full is NULL)
```

It can be more optimized and much faster query, than the first, which uses window function. It depends on your database structure (e.g. indexes using) and numbers of rows